# How to set audio delay for HTML5 videos (desync)

Tags: javascript, html, audio, video

VLC has a nice feature to adjust the audio delay in a video. So I can get audio in sync with the audio when play over my cable connected Sonos Play:5. This speaker has a delay due to audio processing.

Does an HTML5 video tag allow to control the audio delay via JavaScript? I want to set the audio signal -1500 ms before the video signal.

Answer (score 2):

HTML5 video player doesn't support that. Maybe you can find a library for that.

Comment: If there can be a library then there must be a JavaScript command or API.